# akka.net Tell (object) vs Tell (object, IActorRef)

Tags: c#, akka.net

What is the difference? As I understood the Tell (object, IActorRef) sends original sender. But why not to use just the Forward method?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of `actorRef.Tell(msg)` as a shortcut for `actorRef.Tell(msg, Context.Self)`, while `actorRef.Forward(msg)` keeps original message Sender. This also mean, that you need an active actor context in the background to have any meaningful Sender defined.

Using `Tell(object, IActorRef)` allows you to set Sender to any actor ref you like, including things like impersonation as another actor or `ActorRefs.NoSender`, which may be used i.e. to reduce size of a payload send over the wire, as the message sender won't be serialized.

**In some of remote scenarios, if you don't expect to send an answer to a `Sender`, using `actorRef.Tell(msg, ActorRefs.NoSender)` may bring nice performance benefit.**

Why? `IActorRef` is serialized as URI string (example: *akka.tcp://system-name@localhost:9001/user/parent/child*). When you're sending small messages i.e. stock price ticks or a game character position changes, this may mean that the most expensive part of your payload is actually a Sender.

Deserializing `IActorRef` also takes some extra time, because actor provider needs to resolve correct message transport for it.

For those reasons, if you don't need the `Sender`, using `ActorRefs.NoSender` may be a valid option.